# Adding field to table using QGIS graphic modeler?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes, qgis-modeler

I was wondering if anyone could help as I'm struggling to get anything out of the QGIS graphic modeler.  I need to be able to add a new field to an attribute table and update that field with a value that the user will enter.

Is there any way to do that with the graphic modeler?

I have no programming skills whatsoever.

Comment: Probably you want to leave the modeller alone. Add the new field with Field Calculator and then set up a Form for data input.

Comment: yes I've done that but I was trying to find a way to automize actions in our workflow. I've done it before with ArcGis so was wondering if I could do the same with QGIS and the modeler seemed to be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it combining Field Calculator and the String input, where you can set manually the value or formula.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, how if the user want to add manually the value?is it possible?