# Compatibility PyQt5 and PyQt4

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt5

I'm having some compatibility problems with `PyQt5`, as expected some of the scripts I wrote are not working.

My biggest issues are with these two `PyQt4` functions:

```
layer.pendingFields()

layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('Layer_Name')[0]
```

Is there a comparable function in `PyQt5`?

Does it work like the old functions?

In general it would be great to have something like a dictionary, where you could look  for the old function and see the relate translation or substitutes in `PyQt5`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming when you say "PyQt5", you mean you are using QGIS 3.x. In which case:

```
layer.pendingFields()
```

becomes:

```
layer.fields()
```

---

And:

```
layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('Layer_Name')[0]
```

becomes:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Layer_Name')[0]
```

---

You can read [here about the API changes](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html) and [here for the PyQt4 and PyQt5 differences](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly. I'll read the informations more carefully

Comment: @Furio - Most welcome, glad it helped :)