# Batch add multiple columns to a shapefile

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, batch

I am working on a process and during that process for each project I need to add 16 new fields as text strings to my shapefile. T_1, R_1, S_1, QS_1,... these 4 fields out to "_4" .

[image]

My scripting knowledge is not quite up to par but learning.

Answer (score 1):

Search for the Add Field (Data Management) tool, right click it, select batch. Input your parameters per field, press the + sign to add all those you need. Can use this within a model or script

Comment: do you any suggestions on how to add this to a model in QGIS  or save the process some how. Thanks for  your help

Comment: oh sorry about that, you didn't specify QGIS, I was referring to a solution with ArcGIS. Im sure the process will be similar though

Comment: Also  this only allows me to add one field at a time to multiple .shp

Comment: You can use the same input table (same shapefile) multiple times in the tool, just have it as your input table 16 times

Answer (score 0):

After finding some script i changed it up a bit and it worked great

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
```

for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if layer.wkbType() == QGis.WKBPoint:
        with edit(layer):
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("T_1", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("R_1", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("S_1", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("QS_1", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("T_2", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("R_2", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("S_2", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("QS_2", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("T_3", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("R_3", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("S_3", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("QS_3", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("T_4", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("R_4", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("S_4", QVariant.String) ] )
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("QS_4", QVariant.String) ] )

```
else:
    pass
```

This post helped me down the road to figure this out:
[Add multiple fields to a batch of layers in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226890/add-multiple-fields-to-a-batch-of-layers-in-qgis)``

Comment: ok i have come back to this code after a while and i now am stumped on why this in not working .. any guidance would be great!  i am getting the following on each line of code :"File "<input>", line 6
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("T_1", QVariant.String) ] )
    ^"

Comment: how do i update this for Bonn 2.2