# How to make default field in Python Scripts for Processing Framework (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am building a Python Scripts for Processing Framework

https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/processing.html

I know how to make default value when the data type is number or boolean:

```
##Distance=number 50
##carry_test=boolean True
```

I also know how to make fields in the layer into a drop down table and let user choose from:

```
##input_layer=vector
##cal_field=field input_layer
```

Is there a way to populate a default field as well? Say the layer has the following fields:

```
fid, name, type, color
```

Normally everytime the user has to check the drop down to choose 'type'. So it is kind of trouble, is there a way to choose the 'type' everytime when the input_layer has the field 'type'?

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you need to populate ? You might need to ask for a new field name, then launch an update on your new field within the code like in here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236745/updating-field-with-layer-name-on-multiple-layers-with-pyqgis-script/

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is currently possible as at the moment, you can only specify:

```
##Field=[optional] field [number|string] Parentinput
```

where:

- `Field` - Name of the field parameter in the GUI.
- `[optional]` - Optional option to make it...optional.
- `field` - The parameter used to list the fields in the layer.
- `[number|string]` - Optional filter to only list numeric or string fields in the layer.
- `Parentinput` - The layer to read the fields from.

---

In the more [recent processing version](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/core/parameters.py#L1382), you will also be able to filter `date fields` but there doesn't to be a method (yet) to allow default values for fields. You can always ask this as a [feature request](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis) though.