# Writing PyQGIS script to modify layer (add field and fill it) inside QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have the following PyQGIS script with QGIS 3 that tries to ask for a layer, add a new field in that layer and modify the value of this field. But the code doesn't work. I get either **Seems there is no valid script in the file** when I use `layer = QgsVectorLayer(Layer)` or **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isValid'** when I use `QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString` :

```
##Layer=vector
context = QgsProcessingContext()
layer= QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString(Layer, context)

layer.startEditing()

if layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex("new_col_name") == -1:
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("new_col_name", QVariant.String)])
layer.updateFields()

id_new_col= feuilles.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex("new_col_name")

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
  column_value= feature["column"]
  ... some operations ...
  layer.changeAttributeValue(feature.id(), id_new_col, new_column_value)

layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Are you creating a processing script? In QGIS 3.x the Python interface has been redesigned. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282773/writing-a-python-processing-script-with-qgis-3-0

Answer (score 7):

Not sure how to prompt for a layer, but working code below (with a shapefile) uses the currently selected layer.  Note that the new field name was shortened due to name length constraints on shapefiles.

```
layer = iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
layer.startEditing()

if layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex("new_col_na") == -1:
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("new_col_na", QVariant.String)])
    layer.updateFields()

id_new_col= layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex("new_col_na")

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    layer.changeAttributeValue(feature.id(), id_new_col, "val")

layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: If I want to add a specific column to selected layers only in Qgis?