# How to return output a raster layer in a custom processing script in Pyqgis

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-3

I've written a couple of custom scripts for vector shapefiles by following the template provided in QGIS. I am now trying to write a script which will use gdal algorithms to process layers. I have found a great guide [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282773/writing-a-python-processing-script-with-qgis-3-0) on how to adapt the template for raster layers. My question is if I use a gdal algorithm, how do I pass it to the output to be returned by the script?

For example, if I have `rasterized = processing.run("gdal:rasterize", ...` in the calculations part, how do I then pass that to the `output_path_raster_a = self.parameterAsOutputLayer...`

Comment: Could you add a full minimal example?