# Adding scripts to Processing toolbox via PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

Is there a way for adding new Processing scripts into Processing toolbox using PyQGIS?

In the GUI, I can click on "Add script to toolbox", but I want to add scripts using PyQGIS.

[image: Add script by GUI]

QGIS version: 3.16

Comment: Did you have a look at this answer - maybe it helps: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282773/writing-a-python-processing-script-with-qgis-3-0/284410#284410

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that using the code snippet below (adapted from the [QGIS Resource Sharing plugin](https://github.com/QGIS-Contribution/QGIS-ResourceSharing)):

```
import os.path
import shutil
import glob
from processing.script import ScriptUtils

my_scripts_dir = "/path/to/your/scripts/"
count = 0
qgis_scripts_dir = ScriptUtils.defaultScriptsFolder()

# Copy scripts from your script dir to QGIS script dir
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(my_scripts_dir, '*.py')):
    try:
        shutil.copy(filename, qgis_scripts_dir)
        count += 1
    except OSError as e:
        print("Couldn't install script '{}'!".format(filename))

# Finally, refresh the algorithms for the Processing script provider
if count:
    QgsApplication.processingRegistry().providerById("script").refreshAlgorithms()
```

---

*Note: If you are going to add your scripts while QGIS is starting, you will need to check that the `script` provider is already set. Something like:*

```
if QgsApplication.processingRegistry().providerById('script'):
    ...
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have the same action as <kbd>Add Script to Toolbox...</kbd>, execute the code below :

```py
# import the script
from processing.script.AddScriptFromFileAction import AddScriptFromFileAction

# get the reference to the current processing toolbox
toolbox = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QgsDockWidget, "ProcessingToolbox")
# create an instance
script_add = AddScriptFromFileAction()
# add the reference to the current toolbox
script_add.toolbox = toolbox
# execute the script to open a Python script
script_add.execute()
```

You can look at what the `AddScriptFromFileAction` do in [this script](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/script/AddScriptFromFileAction.py).

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but i want only actualize scripts in scripts folder, because i copy script files in openProject macro function. Problem is in copying files, when files are copied after open project.

Comment: Look at this code line : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/32e5ec024c8ff37b398304d39fa9d93a15779f94/python/plugins/processing/script/AddScriptFromFileAction.py#L64

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the pythonscript to the user profiles folder, e.g. under windows it would be:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\profilename\processing\scripts

as a python script it would be something like:

```
import shutil
shutil.copy2('/src/dir/myprocess.py', 'C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/profilename/processing/scripts/myprocess.py')
```

you have to adjust username and profilename in the path. the default profilename is in QGIS: default

Comment: Yes, is good solution, but in opened QGIS project does not work it. Script (file) is not changed after copying. Changes in script will be accepted after reopen project.

Comment: ok that is true...